# Отследить событие, когда пользователь открыл диалоговое окно выбора файла, и не выбрав файла, закрыл

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток! Можно ли отследить событие, когда пользователь открыл диалоговое окно выбора файла, и не выбрав файла, закрыл?

Answer (score 2):

Работает только в IE (**[посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt2bS/)**)

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    // IE suspends timeouts until after the file dialog closes
    $('#file__box').click(function (event) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if ($('#file__box').val().length === 0) {
                alert('test');
            }
        }, 0);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, это будет change:

```
$('#file__box').on('change', function(){

    var fileName = $(this).val();
    if (!fileName) { alert('Ничего не ввдеено'); }

});
```

Пример тут: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/LK8G4/

Comment: насколько я знаю, событие change происходит, когда значение инпута меняется. Если просто закрыть окно выбора, оно не произойдет. Ваш пример не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю нужно брать хитростью. Напишем код

```
<input type="file" id="test">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var t = $("#test");
    t.focus(function() { console.log('focus'); });
    t.blur(function() { console.log('blur'); });
</script>
```

И посмотрим как работает при том поведении, которое Вы описали.

```
focus 
blur 
focus
```

Т.е. фокус ставится, теряется, ставится.
Алгоритм примерно следующий:

```
    var inputFocusMap = [];
    $("#test").focus(function() {
        var val = document.getElementById('test').value; // Через jQuery то val() не берётся.
        inputFocusMap.push(val);
        var last = inputFocusMap[inputFocusMap.length - 1] || false;
        var prev = inputFocusMap[inputFocusMap.length - 2] || false;
        if (last == prev) {
            console.log('Не изменилось');
        } else {
            console.log('Изменилось');
        }
    });
```